# В разделе “Отзывы на сообщение” инструментов модератора нет множественной формы у слова "сообщение"

Tags: дефект, локализация, инструменты-модератора, 10k-tools

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback/underrated?filter=all

Сверху:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И снизу:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В английской версии там «posts», поэтому надо бы найти строку традусёрную.

Comment: @älёxölüt оно? https://ru.traducir.win/string/176

Comment: почему множественное число для one?

Comment: @älёxölüt ух, не увидел, что это для one.

Comment: Сверху пофикшено. Про низ надо бы у КМ спросить, у него есть тул, позволяющий из гуйни в транзифекс id показывать.